# How to replicate clicking button combinations in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, click, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to replicate button combination clicks in JavaScript. How can I achieve that ?

For example I can do something like this:
`element.click()`

So, I want to do something similar, something like this:

`(CTRL+Z).click()`

Comment: Hi noiseymur, can you add some code you've tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=trigger+ctrl-z+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.